# Get record data from recordId within Aura with no Apex controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force-recorddata

I have a Quick Action button on the Highlight Panel of Case page that launches a Lightning Aura Comp (QA: Detail page button with URL). Through pageReference, I was able to access the parent CaseId. Now that I have CaseId, how can I fetch few field values of this Case record without Apex controller class?

I've tried:

CMP

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="CaseId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="caseRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  fields="Sample__c"
  recordId="{!v.CaseId}"
  targetFields="{!v.caseRecord}"
  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
  recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
  />
```

JS

```
handleRecordUpdated: function(component, event, helper){
   console.log('Inside Handle method'); //Not getting logged. 
    var eventParams = event.getParams();
    if(eventParams.changeType === "LOADED") {
        console.log("Case loaded with:" + component.get("v.caseRecord"));
    }
}
```

I couldn't get any log for the above debug statement. So, not sure if the function `handleRecordUpdated` even gets fired.
I do have implementation for creating a subtab within `doInit`.

**Update**: To give more context, I have a Case landing page where we have a Highlight panel. Here, we are implementing a QuickAction button of display type: Detail Page Button with URL as: /lightning/cmp/c__MySampleAuraComponent. This Aura comp contains doInit where we are using `workspaceAPI` to open a subtab for a custom object's standard record creation form. So, to prepopulate few fields from Case object, I was trying to fetch parent case field values. I know I could go down the Apex controller path, but decided to give it a try without it to minimize code maintenance.

I have tried Lightning Message Services to publish the necessary fields, but no luck with QuickAction implementation on the highlights panel.

**Update 11/22**: I am setting the CaseId value within my `doInit` function and I can verify the data in my console. But not sure why it is not getting passed to `force:recordData` as I don't see any log from `handleRecordUpdated`.

Comment: Do you get a message in recordError? That would be hint as to why handleRecordUpdated is not called. If the fields and record Id are set correctly, everything should work.

Comment: @sfdcfox I couldn't get any log for recordError variable. I could see v.CaseId value set from my doInit function. As a matter of fact, I couldn't get any log from the function: handleRecordUpdated.

Comment: @AustinEvans could this be a case-sensitive issue ? check if CaseId is referenced everywhere with uppercase "C"

Comment: @AustinEvans also crosscheck the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) if parameter is named correctly with c__ when using pageReference

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reload the record after you set the Case Id.

```
component.set('v.CaseId', 'case-id-here');
component.find('recordLoader').reloadRecord(true);
```

This will make sure your record is reloaded after Id is updated.

Comment: I am afraid I could do that as I am landing on a record creation page. The other problem I am facing right now is - I have to close the tab that opens up my aura component which then redirects to record creation page.

Comment: @AustinEvans not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate with an example? When using reloadRecord it is triggering the handleRecordUpdated as you want.

Comment: I would give this approach a try and get back to you after Monday. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that you have a field called `Sample__c` on the Case object, because the fields mentioned in the `fields` attribute should be existing/correct standard or custom fields.

For example: try `fields="Id,Status"` and see if that will work.
Thank you.

Comment: The field I specified in my component is valid and it exists on the object definition. So, that's not causing any issue. Any other approach?